# Sphinx Docs not rendering Styling/CSS after running `make html`

Tags: python-3.x, python-sphinx

I have a project and use Sphinx, combined with the sphinx_rtd_theme, to produce documentation.

Basically when I run the `make html` command to build the docs, when I try open the .html, it just looks like bare html with no CSS. No styling at all.

[image: raw html sphinx docs page]

I've seen a few posts on here and on Github where this has happened, but that seemed to be related to when one is hosting on Github Pages and having `.nojekyll` files. In my scenario, I'm just trying to render it locally and it still has no styling?

I will also note that whilst below you will see I'm trying to use the `sphinx_rtd_theme`, I tried just using `html_theme = "classic"`, but that still fails to render any styling.

Can anyone help solve this? I'm happy to post additional information if that helps.

Conf.py

The `conf.py` looks like the below. I've included what I believe to be relevant, and missed out stuff in between marked by the `...` dots.

```
...

import codecs
import os
import re
import sys
import sphinx_rtd_theme
from recommonmark.parser import CommonMarkParser

...


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------
...


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

# If your documentation needs a minimal Sphinx version, state it here.
#
# needs_sphinx = '1.0'

# Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be
# extensions coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom
# ones.
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.doctest",
    "sphinx.ext.todo",
    "sphinx.ext.coverage",
    "sphinx.ext.imgmath",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",
    "sphinx.ext.githubpages",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
    "sphinx_rtd_theme",
]

# Add any paths that contain templates here, relative to this directory.
templates_path = ["_templates"]

# The suffix(es) of source filenames.
# You can specify multiple suffix as a list of string:
source_parsers = {
    ".md": CommonMarkParser,
}
source_suffix = [".rst", ".md"]

# The master toctree document.
master_doc = "index"

# The language for content autogenerated by Sphinx. Refer to documentation
# for a list of supported languages.
#
# This is also used if you do content translation via gettext catalogs.
# Usually you set "language" from the command line for these cases.
language = None

# List of patterns, relative to source directory, that match files and
# directories to ignore when looking for source files.
# This pattern also affects html_static_path and html_extra_path .
exclude_patterns = []

# The name of the Pygments (syntax highlighting) style to use.
pygments_style = "sphinx"


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

# The theme to use for HTML and HTML Help pages.  See the documentation for
# a list of builtin themes.
#
html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"

...
```

Relevant installed versions

```
sphinx-rtd-theme               0.5.1
sphinxcontrib-applehelp        1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp          1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp         1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath           1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp           1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml  1.1.4
Sphinx                         3.4.3
```

**Edit**

When I run `make html`, the output in the terminal is as follows:

```
(proejct_name) [...]$ make html
sphinx-apidoc -f ../project_name -o source/
Creating file source/project_name.rst.
Creating file source/modules.rst.
Regenerated API docs in ./source
sphinx-build -b html  source build/html
Running Sphinx v3.4.3
loading pickled environment... done
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [config changed ('source_parsers')] 8 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] update_assumptions                                                                                                                                                       
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] update_assumptions                                                                                                                                                        
generating indices... genindex py-modindex done
highlighting module code... [100%] project_name.utilities                                                                                                                        
writing additional pages... search done
copying images... [100%] _static/update_assumptions.png                                                                                                                                            
copying static files... done
copying extra files... done
dumping search index in English (code: en)... done
dumping object inventory... done
build succeeded.

The HTML pages are in build/html.
```

Comment: What's the output of the actual command? Any warnings about missing static files perhaps?

Comment: Hey @MadPhysicist, I just edited to add the output of the `make html` command.

Comment: Do a `make clean && make html` to ensure you do not build from cached files. When you open a file in a web browser, use the developer tools to determine what is missing. It sounds like a CSS or JS file is either not getting copied over or lacks sufficient permissions for you to view it.

Comment: Hi @StevePiercy, thanks for your comment. I think you're right, when I look through in developer tools, I can see the html linking the the stylesheets (.css files), and those files exist, but if I try open them directly I'm getting a 403 forbidden error. I think it is a permissions thing on the cloud container. If I download the entire build/ folder to my desktop, I'm able to render the .css and formatting.

Comment: Can you change the permissions on the file and its parent directories?